# Expose type of local TypeScript class outside factory function

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to use a factory to manage some of my dependency injection and so I am creating a local class inside of a function. The JavaScript framework I am using (AngularJS) will inject the return value of the function into the constructor.

How can I reference the type of the returned class `Record` from outside the factory function?

```
/** Define factory to create Record classes */
export default function RecordFactory($window) {
  return class Record { // I want to reference this class as a type
    doSomething() {
      // use $window service
    }
  }

}

/**
 * Controller for page with returned class of RecordFactory injected
 * into the constructor
 */
class RecordPageCtrl {
  record
  constructor(Record) { // How do I specify the type of Record here?
    this.record = new Record();
  }
}

// Dependency Injection is handled by AngularJS
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('Record', RecordFactory)
  .controller('RecordPageCtrl', RecordPageCtrl)
```

*Note: I'm trying to avoid maintaining a interface with all of the methods on the `Record` class.*

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
namespace Factored {
  // Class Record wrapped in namespace only to distinguish from other Record usages
  export class Record { // I want to reference this class as a type
    doSomething() {
      // use $window service
    }
  };
}

/** Define factory to create Record classes */
export default function RecordFactory($window) {
  return Factored.Record; // return class reference
}

/**
 * Controller for page with returned class of RecordFactory injected
 * into the constructor
 */
class RecordPageCtrl {
  record: Factored.Record;
  constructor(Record: typeof Factored.Record) { // Referencing namespaced class
    this.record = new Record();
    this.record.doSomething();
  }
}

// Dependency Injection is handled by AngularJS
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('Record', RecordFactory)
  .controller('RecordPageCtrl', RecordPageCtrl)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I can't reproduce this. I can't access the injected service (e.g. `$window`) from the `Record` class.

Answer (score 0):

I've reconsidered how the factory is created and the services are injected into classes like `Record`. By passing the service in through the constructor, a factory can easily pass in the service and allow AngularJS to handle dependency injection.

```
/** Class where service needs to be injected */
class Record {
  constructor(private myInjectedService) {}
    doSomething() {
      // use myService
      this.myInjectedService.log('Hello World');
    }
}

/** Define factory to create Record class instances */
function RecordFactory(MyService) {
  return new Record(MyService); // return a new class
}

/**
 * Controller for page 
 * RecordFactory return variable is injected into the constructor
 */
class RecordPageCtrl {
  constructor(public Record: Record) {
    this.Record.doSomething();
  }
}

/** Service to inject into Record class */
class MyService {
    log(message: string) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}

let myServiceInst = new MyService();

// directly instantiated
let factoryInstance = RecordFactory(myServiceInst);
new RecordPageCtrl(factoryInstance);

// Dependency Injection handled by AngularJS
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('Record', RecordFactory)
  .service('MyService', MyService)
  .controller('RecordPageCtrl', RecordPageCtrl)
```

Note, if you want to be able to create multiple instances of the `Record` class where the factory is being injected, you will need to have the factory return another factory which instantiates the function when called.